# How to use/install custom Directshow filter

Tags: c++, filter, directshow

I have custom compiled directshow filter - filter.DLL - but how to use, or install this filter in system?

Answer (score 6):

Usually you register the directshow filter into system by calling (from an elevated command prompt window on windows vista/7) `regsvr32 filter.dll`.

After the registration process you can use your filter with a directshow graph viewing application:

- GraphEdit (graphedt.exe), installed by Windows SDK (ex. "c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\graphedt.exe" )
- [GraphStudio](http://blog.monogram.sk/janos/tools/monogram-graphstudio/)

After testing your filter with the above programs you can use it in a C++/C# client application.

Answer (score 3):

The main way would be to register the filter file with `regsvr32 filter.dll` and than create the filter with it's CLSID in your application.

If the filter are in the same codebase as the application, you can just create the filter with `new` and use it.

I prefer to load the filter.dll with `CoLoadLibrary` to get the IClassFactory of the filter and create the filter. You can test this with [GraphStudioNext](http://code.google.com/p/graph-studio-next/). You can find sample source code to load a filter this way [here](http://code.google.com/p/graph-studio-next/source/browse/trunk/src/FilterFromFile.cpp).

Answer (score 1):

Like Cristian said, people typically register the filter on the system.  But I prefer not to do this for [a few reasons](http://goldfishforthought.blogspot.com/2008/04/n-habits-of-highly-defective-directshow.html).  In particular, see the section on "Registering Filters with the Operating System."

I think nine times out of ten, you're better off instantiating with new.  See [AppFilter on Geraint Davis' page](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/downloads.htm) for an example.