# DSPack: how to connect PushSource to videocap?

Tags: delphi, dspack

I want to use `PushSource` filter to capture but I need to "connect" it to "videocap" sample. This filter is not a standalone filter, so it can't be enumerated as capture device, also I dont want it to convert like that

Comment: I use DSPack a lot. Can you be more specific? Are you trying to capture still images?

Comment: I try to capture video. (PushSourceDesktop) I tried it with GraphEdit and it worked, its just not a filter to connect, but I know there are methods to include filters into your own application instead of registering with filesystem.

Comment: similar like this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560855/how-to-use-install-custom-directshow-filter I just no idea how to include it...

Answer (score 2):

Well, I use Nvidia Encoder Filter that does not show up in GraphEdit. To do that I just define the GUID:

```
Const
CLSID_NVIDIA_VideoEncoderFilter : TGUID = '{B63E31D0-87B5-477f-B224-4A35B6BECED6}';
```

Then I create the filter in memory like that:

```
Var
  N: IBaseFilter;
begin
  CoCreateInstance(CLSID_NVIDIA_VideoEncoderFilter, Nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter, N);
  if Assigned(N) then
  Begin
  // connect to any filter that you can use in your system
  End;
```

Also you can see this "hidden" filter in your GraphEdit now.

Edit: Here is the code that I link filters. It searches for every pin that may be connected to the next filter. This code connects audio out pins to audio in pins and video out pins to video in pins etc. It is very flexible.

```
Procedure Connect(Builder: IGraphBuilder; SourceFilter, DestFilter: IBaseFilter);
Var
  SourceEnum, DestEnum: IEnumPins;
  SourcePin, DestPin: IPin;
  FI: _FilterInfo;
  S, D: String;
Begin
  SourceFilter.QueryFilterInfo(FI);
  S := FI.achName;
  DestFilter.QueryFilterInfo(FI);
  D := FI.achName;
  SourceFilter.EnumPins(SourceEnum);
  DestFilter.EnumPins(DestEnum);
  DestEnum.Reset;
  While DestEnum.Next(1, DestPin, Nil) = S_OK Do
  Begin
    SourceEnum.Reset;
    While SourceEnum.Next(1, SourcePin, Nil) = S_OK Do
      If Builder.Connect(SourcePin, DestPin) = S_OK Then
      Begin
        SourceEnum := Nil;
        DestEnum := Nil;
        SourcePin := Nil;
        DestPin := Nil;
        Exit;
      End;
  End;
  SourceEnum := Nil;
  DestEnum := Nil;
  SourcePin := Nil;
  DestPin := Nil;
  Raise Exception.Create(Format('There is no pin from %s to connect to %d', [S, D]));
End;
```

Now you can use this method with your filters as in the following code

```
Var
  SourceFilter, DestFilter: IBaseFilter;
  Builder: IGraphBuilder;
Begin
  SourceFilter := SrcFilter As IBaseFilter;
  DestFilter := DstFilter As IBaseFilter;
  Builder := FilterGraph As IGraphBuilder;
  Connect(Builder, SourceFilter, DestFilter);
End;
```

Hope this helps. We were all newbies once ;)

Comment: thanx for the answers for now. Could you detail the "connect to any filter" part? :) I have no idea how to connect it to VideoSourceFilter component... or what to

Comment: Sure. I use to encrypt the video and then connect this filter to a "MatroskaMuxer" filter that I create, then connect it to a file writer filter and I have a graph that records H264 encoded video into a Matroska file. Use IGraphBuilder's Connect method to connect pins. Hint: GraphBuilder := FilterGraph1 As IGraphBuilder;

Comment: how to create "dstFilter" as Avi output file, or streaming media?

Comment: Add a new filter to your form (or create it with CoCreateInstance, doesn't matter), double click and select AVI Mux from DirectShow filters. Add another filter and double click it, select File Writer, set file name. Set their filter graph property (probably FilterGraph1). This will create an AVI file. For streaming media, you can use ASFWriter component of DSPack. Check this out: http://www.vwlowen.co.uk/directshow/asfwriter/page02.htm