# dspack, pushsource how to use it?

Tags: delphi, filter, directshow, dspack

I saw some topic, like [How to use/install custom Directshow filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560855/how-to-use-install-custom-directshow-filter) to register a filter, but no code how to use it. Can anybody show a sample how to actual use that filter (pushsource, pushdesktop) to save into AVI?

Comment: You build the pipeline the same way, just instantiating the filter directly as opposed through COM's `CoCreateInstance`. What have you tried?

Comment: I was trying with a grabber sample "vidcap", but it only accepts video sources. When I tried to enforce pushdesktop, it dropped an exception: not supported interface. Is pushsource enough to capture and broadcast/save video stream at all?