# How to add a Video Encoder to windows to be recognized by DirectShow

Tags: c#, video-encoding, directshow.net

**i don't understand somethings about video encoder if you could help me clarify:**

- where the encoders exist in the system?
- how's directshow recognize them?
- what's the encoders supported by directshows and how to add them?

thank you for reading my questions, and for any help.

Answer (score 1):

A very usefull tool for things like that is GraphEdit (part of DirectShow SDK and can be downloaded for example here: http://www.videohelp.com/tools/GraphEdit)
If you click Graph -> Insert Filters you see a list of all installed filters and can see their file location.
To register a filter you can use (in command prompt): `regsvr32 filter.dll` 
(As described here: [How to use/install custom Directshow filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560855/how-to-use-install-custom-directshow-filter))

Comment: thank you very much it's very useful as you said. it helps me find that they are in program file, so do you know how directshow recognize them, are there some references added to the registry?

Answer (score 1):

See [Choosing a Compression Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374572%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> To enumerate the video or audio compressors available on the user's system, do the following: [...]

There is also a code snippet there to enumerate and instantiate the compressors/encoders.

You tagged the question as [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and not [directshow.net](/questions/tagged/directshow.net), so you might also need to look at DirectShow.NET for accessing DirectShow API from managed code. DirectShow.NET also provides you with samples.

Comment: thank you for your replay i will see those DirectShow.NET samples